# AppStore, what happens if your app gets approved?

Tags: iphone, app-store

So i'm developing an application that has to be released the same day the website launches. since we don't have an exact control when the app will be approved i'm putting it up for approval now.

but what happens then ? is it automatically in the app store ? can we (or do we ..) keep the application on hold .. when do we need to put a price on it, the day you put it up for approval or when it gets approved ..

are there things we should know ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set a "release date" when you upload the application to Apple for approval. Once your app is approved, it won't go live until that date.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess once it's approved it's going to be added to the store. This is not to be construed as a "Google It" answer, but I would highly suggest actually contacting Apple support and getting the low-down straight from them.

Comment: -1 for posting a wild-ass guess only four minutes after the question was asked